# In quarkus how to set @RegisterRestClient(configKey = "payment-api.auth-token-api") these configKey at run time

Tags: java, quarkus

In quarkus how to set @RegisterRestClient(configKey = "payment-api.auth-token-api") these configKey at run time.
i want to remove "payment-api.auth-token-api" from application.yaml.I have a other service in that from variable i want to put the configkey value dynamically.

i am trying for a way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to cal the key `payment-api` (instead of `payment-api.auth-token-api`). That will make things easier in general.

Any the REST Client [configuration](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#create-the-configuration) can be provided by any of the ways that Quarkus [supports](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources).

So for example you could use Java system properties and add `-Dquarkus.rest-client.payment-api.url=someurl`
`

Comment: I cant put in system properties too. i have an other api service using that i want to integrate at the RegisterRestClient value
let say 
@Inject
ProviderService providerService;

var config = providerservice.retrieve("");
var endUrl=config.getAuthTokenAPI();

this endUrl needed to go dynamically at the RegisterRestClient();